# Efficient calculation of months (continuous) since last birthday at snapshot date

Tags: r, plyr, lubridate

I have a data.frame that contains two date columns, one for date of birth (`DOB`) for an individual, and a reference point in time (`Snapshot.Date`), let's say it's the date we last saw that individual. There are other columns (omitted), so I'd ideally like the results to be added as a column to my existing data.frame.

I would like to calculate how many months (continuous), between the individuals last birthday (relative to the Snapshot.Date) and the `Snapshot.Date`.

I've tried a plyr solution and a base sapply solution, and they are both slower than I expected they would be -- (and I need to process one million rows in my 'real' data.frame)

First,  here is a test dataset. 20 original records (with the 'special' case of Feb 29th, only existing in a leap year).

```
data.test  = structure(list(Snapshot.Date = structure(c(1433030400, 1396224000, 
                                                        1375228800, 1396224000, 1383177600, 1362009600, 1367280000, 1369958400, 
                                                        1346371200, 1348963200, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 
                                                        1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1435622400, 1346371200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), DOB = structure(c(-268790400, 
                                                                     -155692800, -955065600, -551232000, -149644800, -774230400, -485395200, 
                                                                     -17625600, -131932800, -387244800, 545961600, 18489600, -230515200, 
                                                                     441676800, -32745600, 775180800, 713491200, 483235200, 114307200, 
                                                                     -815443200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("Snapshot.Date", 
                                                                                                                                              "DOB"), row.names = c(32806L, 21294L, 14880L, 21730L, 17525L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    8516L, 11068L, 11751L, 2564L, 3832L, 802276L, 1031697L, 129222L, 
                                                                                                                                                                    588224L, 1093247L, 878037L, 370736L, 709108L, 861908L, 2199L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the function for calculating months (I'm sure this can be improved too).

```
months_since_last_birthday = function(CurrentDate, DateOfBirth)
{
  last_birthday = DateOfBirth

  if(month(last_birthday) == 2 & day(last_birthday) == 29) # this birthday only occurs once every four years, let's reset them to be the 28th
  {
    day(last_birthday) = 28 
  }

  year(last_birthday) = year(CurrentDate)

  if(last_birthday > CurrentDate)
  {
    last_birthday = last_birthday - years(1) #last year's birthday is the most recent occurrence
  }

  return(as.period(new_interval(last_birthday, CurrentDate)) / months(1)) 
}
```

For the base 20 records, here is the desired output:

```
       Snapshot.Date        DOB Months.Since.Birthday
32806      2015-05-31 1961-06-26            11.1643836
21294      2014-03-31 1965-01-25             2.1972603
14880      2013-07-31 1939-09-27            10.1315068
21730      2014-03-31 1952-07-14             8.5589041
17525      2013-10-31 1965-04-05             6.8547945
8516       2013-02-28 1945-06-20             8.2630137
11068      2013-04-30 1954-08-15             8.4931507
11751      2013-05-31 1969-06-11            11.6575342
2564       2012-08-31 1965-10-27            10.1315068
3832       2012-09-30 1957-09-24             0.1972603
802276     2015-06-30 1987-04-21             2.2958904
1031697    2015-06-30 1970-08-03            10.8876712
129222     2015-06-30 1962-09-12             9.5917808
588224     2015-06-30 1983-12-31             5.9863014
1093247    2015-06-30 1968-12-18             6.3945205
878037     2015-06-30 1994-07-26            11.1315068
370736     2015-06-30 1992-08-11            10.6246575
709108     2015-06-30 1985-04-25             2.1643836
861908     2015-06-30 1973-08-16            10.4602740
2199       2012-08-31 1944-02-29             6.0986301
```

Scaling up the dataset for benchmarking:

```
# Make 5000 records total for benchmarking, didn't replicate Feb 29th
# since it is a very rare case in the data
set.seed(1)
data.test = rbind(data.test, data.test[sample(1:19, size = 4980, replace = TRUE),])

start.time = Sys.time()
res = suppressMessages(adply(data.test , 1, transform, Months.Since.Birthday = months_since_last_birthday(Snapshot.Date, DOB)))
end.time = Sys.time()

# end.time - start.time
# Time difference of 1.793945 mins

start.time = Sys.time()
data.test$Months.Since.Birthday = suppressMessages(sapply(1:5000, function(x){return(months_since_last_birthday(data.test$Snapshot.Date[x], data.test$DOB[x]))}))
end.time = Sys.time()

# end.time - start.time
# Time difference of 1.743053 mins
```

Am I doing something seriously wrong? Does this seem really slow to you?
Any feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, there are a bunch of built in ways of working with time data in `R`, notably `base::difftime` which may have saved you some trouble.

Taking your above dataset `data.test`:

```
data.test$dif <- round(as.vector(as.double(difftime(strptime(data.test$Snapshot.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), strptime(data.test$DOB, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), units = "days"))) %% 365, 1)
```

or to lay it out more logically (this wont work if you copy paste it).

```
data.test$dif <- 
  round(
    as.vector(
      as.double(
        difftime(
          strptime(data.test$Snapshot.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
          strptime(data.test$DOB, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), units = "days")
        )
      )
      %% 365,
    1)
```

The above uses the `difftime` function to find the difference between the two dates with the given format (`format = "%Y-%m-%d"`) in terms of days, then performs remainder division to get the number of days since the last birthday. I personally think this is a better measure than months because a difference of 2 months between July and August is a different number of days than a 2 month difference between January and February.

**Note**: The above solution does not incorporate leap years. You could easily look up a list of leap years and add 1 day to the checkup or subtract 1 day from the birthday of each individual who lived through that leap year to get an accurate number.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a special case for leap years.